# Inheritance From Constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

I need help understanding how to get something to work.

I've got my base class `Hero()`, from which I derive other instances of, i.e., a `Fighter()` or an `Archer()`. I am trying to set up a lot of the logic in the Hero() class specifically so I reduce the amount of retyping needed. Below are my classes:

```
class Hero
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public int MaxHP { get; set; }

    public int BaseHP { get; set; }

    public int CurrentHP { get; set; }

    public int BaseDodge { get; set; }

    public int Dodge { get; set; }

    public int BaseAttack { get; set; }

    public int Attack { get; set; }

    public int Damage { get; set; }

    public int BaseXP { get; set; }

    public int CurrentXP { get; set; }

    public int NeededXP { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    public int HPLevelInc { get; set; }

    public int AttackLevelInc { get; set; }

    public int DodgeLevelInc { get; set; }

    public int DodgeCap { get; set; }

    public string Ability1Name { get; set; }

    public string Ability2Name { get; set; }

    public string Ability3Name { get; set; }

    public int Ability1Mod { get; set; }

    public int Ability2Mod { get; set; }

    public int Ability3Mod { get; set; }

    public int Ability2CoolDown { get; set; }

    public int Ability3CoolDown { get; set; }

    public int BaseHealMod { get; set; }

    public int HealMod { get; set; }

    public int HealCap { get; set; }

    public int HealLevelInc { get; set; }

    public Hero(int lvl)
    {
        BaseXP = 1000;
        NeededXP = 1000;
        /*
        MaxHP = BaseHP;
        Dodge = BaseDodge;
        Attack = BaseAttack;
        HealMod = BaseHealMod;
        */
        if (lvl > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lvl; i++)
            {
                LevelUp();
            }
        }
    }
    public int getDamage(int abilMod)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randDmg = r.Next(1, Level);
        Damage = Attack + abilMod + randDmg;
        return Damage;
    }
    public void LevelUp()
    {
        BaseXP = (int)Math.Floor(BaseXP * 2.5);
        NeededXP = BaseXP - CurrentXP;
        Level++;
        MaxHP = MaxHP + HPLevelInc;
        CurrentHP = MaxHP;
        Attack = Attack + AttackLevelInc;
        if (Level % 5 == 0 && Dodge < DodgeCap)
            Dodge = Dodge + DodgeLevelInc;
        if (Level % 5 == 0 && HealMod < HealCap)
            HealMod = HealMod + HealLevelInc;
    }
    public void Heal()
    {
        CurrentHP += HealMod;
        if (CurrentHP > BaseHP)
        {
            CurrentHP = BaseHP;
        }
    }
    public void Heal(int extra)
    {
        CurrentHP += HealMod + extra;
        if (CurrentHP > BaseHP)
        {
            CurrentHP = BaseHP;
        }
    }
}
```

Then my `Figher()` looks like this:

```
class Fighter : Hero
{
    public Fighter(int lvl) : base(lvl)
    {
        Name = "Fighter";
        BaseAttack = 10;
        BaseHP = 50;
        BaseDodge = 5;
        HPLevelInc = 7;
        AttackLevelInc = 3;
        DodgeLevelInc = 1;
        DodgeCap = 45;
        BaseHealMod = 5;
        HealCap = 30;
        HealLevelInc = 3;
        Ability1Name = "Ability 1";
        Ability2Name = "Ability 2";
        Ability3Name = "Ability 3";
        Ability2CoolDown = 3;
        Ability3CoolDown = 5;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running in to, is that when I make an instance of my `Fighter()`, it is increasing the level and the XP, but nothing else.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fighter F = new Fighter(7);

        Console.WriteLine("Level: " + F.Level + " " + F.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Hit Points: " + F.CurrentHP);
        Console.WriteLine("cXP: " + F.CurrentXP + "  XP2L: " + F.NeededXP);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This outputs as:

```
Level: 7 Fighter
Hit Points: 0
cXP: 0  XP2L: 610342
```

Can someone help me to understand how to implement this and get it to work? I think I'm missing something simple, but I'm not certain what.

Comment: First, consider if you really want all of those properties to have public setters. My guess is that some should be private. Second, add arguments to your base class constructor to set all of the properties used in LevelUp.  Finally, pass the default values for your Fighter class to the base class when you call the base class constructor from the Fighter constructor.

Comment: `Fighter` does not seem to add any new behavior nor state from a vanilla Hero. Are you sure Fighter is not just an instance of Hero?

Answer (score 0):

You have the **obvious** output since the base constructor is getting fire before the derived & at that point the values are not initialise with what you have set in Fighter's constructor.

There's a hacky way of doing it using an instance variable initializer:

```
using System;

class Hero
{
    public Hero()
    {
        //code
    }  
}

class Fighter: Hero
{
    private readonly int ignoreMe = BeforeBaseConstructorCall();

    public Fighter()
    {
    }

    private static int BeforeBaseConstructorCall()
    {
        //initailise the properties.
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
          //calls Fighter first & then Base()
          Fighter obj =  new Fighter();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your level increase is because upon instantiating Fighter subclass it also instantiate your base class Hero and run the logic in your base.

The culprit is the way you design your base.
And you should not put any logic within the constructor as much as possible that leads to your problem.

Your base Hero constructor requires parameter that force your subclass to instantiate base Hero in child constructor and all that will inherit from your base class will be forced to do so.

That is why you have this :

```
public class Hero(int lvl) { ... }

public Fighter(int lvl) : base(lvl) {...}
```

If you want to pass the level to your base Hero class without instantiating the base Hero in your subclass remove the base constructor parameter and level it unparameterize and put your logic somewhere else. Subclass inherit from base can use any properties of it.

Something like this:

```
public Hero()
{
  public int level;
  ...
}

public class Fighter : Hero   
{ 
   public class Fighter(int lvl)
   {
      base.level = lvl;
   }
}
```